# Clear "pending_update_count" in Telegram Bot

Tags: webhooks, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I want to clear all `pending_update_count` in my bot!

The output of below command :

```
https://api.telegram.org/botxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/getWebhookInfo
```

*Obviously I replaced the real API token with xxx*

is this :

```
{
 "ok":true,"result":
    {
     "url":"",
     "has_custom_certificate":false,
     "pending_update_count":5154
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have `5154` unread updates til now!! ( I'm pretty sure this pending updates are errors! Because no one uses this Bot! It's just a test Bot)

By the way, this `pending_update_count` number are increasing so fast!
Now that I'm writing this post the number increased `51` and reached to 5205 !

I just want to clear this pending updates.
I'm pretty sure this Bot have been stuck in an infinite loop!

Is there any way to get rid of it?

P.S:

I also cleared the webhook url. But nothing changed!

**UPDATE:**

The output of `getWebhookInfo` is this :

```
{
   "ok":true,
   "result":{
      "url":"https://somewhere.com/telegram/webhook",
      "has_custom_certificate":false,
      "pending_update_count":23,
      "last_error_date":1482910173,
      "last_error_message":"Wrong response from the webhook: 500 Internal Server Error",
      "max_connections":40
   }
}
```

Why I get `Wrong response from the webhook: 500 Internal Server Error` ?

Comment: is your bot **echoing** messages? that's the only reason i can think of

Comment: what prevents you to get this updates and clear counter?

Comment: Please see the updates

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you have two options:

1. set webhook that do nothing, just say 200 OK to telegram's servers. Telegram wiil send all updates to this url and the queque will be cleared.
2. disable webhook and after it get updates by using getUpdates method, after it, turn on webhook again

**Update:**

Problem with webhook on your side. You can try to emulate telegram's POST query on your URL. 
It can be something like this:

```
{"message_id":1,"from":{"id":1,"first_name":"FirstName","last_name":"LastName","username":"username"},"chat":{"id":1,"first_name":"FirstName","last_name":"LastName","username":"username","type":"private"},"date":1460957457,"text":"test message"}
```

You can send this text as a POST query body with PostMan for example, and after it try to debug your backend.

Comment: Method 2 didnt work for me, I don't know what could i Possibly be doing wrong, as I'm getting the info using getupdates, but turning the webhook on again doesn't fix it.
Method 1 I'm not sure how to implement it, is the problem setting the webhook, or where?

Comment: @Danil Pyatnitsev, i also facing the same problem ... can you give us simple example for method 1 ? greatly appreciate your help ...

Answer (score 16):

For anyone looking at this in 2020 and beyond, the Telegram API now supports clearing the pending messages via a `drop_pending_updates` parameter in both `setWebhook` and `deleteWebhook`, as per the [API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook).

Comment: try to hit the URL like this: https://api.telegram.org/botYOURTOKEN/setWebhook?url=https://yoururl.com&drop_pending_updates=true

Answer (score 4):

Just add `return 1;` at the end of your hook method.

**Update:**

Commonly this happens because of queries delay with the database.

Comment: hi there, i also facing the same problem ... can u give us example for this ?

Comment: @Ivan in your function that call by telegram, add only a line of code like ```return 1```; and send something to bot after do.

Comment: something like this ?  
`public function index() {
  $content = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $update = json_decode($content, true); 
 
  $chatID = "12345678";
  $reply = "ok";
 
  return 1;
  
  $API_URL = "https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/";
  $sendto =$API_URL."sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".$reply;
  file_get_contents($sendto);
 }`

Comment: @Ivan Yes! But if you just want to reset pending count do Like this: ```public function(){return 1;}

Comment: @Ivan It was clear! you must! every name that you want.

Comment: im sorry, but it didnt work, i used to do the same thing like you do, and it usually work, but its not working anymore...  i even try to unset the webhook and set it again ...

Answer (score 4):

I solved is like this

```
POST tg.api/bottoken/setWebhook to emtpy "url"
POST tg.api/bottoken/getUpdates
POST tg.api/bottoken/getUpdates with "offset" last update_id appeared before
```

doing this serveral times

```
POST tg.api/bottoken/getWebhookInfo
```

had a look if all away.

```
POST tg.api/bottoken/setWebhook with filled "url"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using webhook, you can follow these steps

1. On your web browser, enter the following url with your right value of **bot**

   [https://api.telegram.org/**bot**/getWebhookInf](https://api.telegram.org/%3Cbot%3E/getWebhookInf)
2. You will get a result like this on your screen

   *{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"**url_value**",...}}*
3. On the displayed result, copy the entire **url_value** without quotes and replace it on this second url
   [https://api.telegram.org/**bot**/setWebhook?url=**url_value**&drop_pending_updates=True](https://api.telegram.org/bot/setWebhook?url=url_value&drop_pending_updates=True)
4. Enter the second url with right **bot** and **url_value** in your web browser then press ENTER

   Done!

Answer (score 0):

i solve it by Change file access permissions file - **set permissions file to 755**

and second increase memory limit in php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

A quick&dirty way is to get a temporary webhook here: https://webhook.site/ and
set your webhook to that (it will answer with a HTTP/200 code everytime, reseting your pending messages to zero)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue for my tele bot after user edited existing message. My bot receives update with editedMessage continuously, but update.hasMessage() was empty. As a result number of updates rocketly increased and my bot stack.

I solved this issue by adding handling for use case when message is missing - send 200 code:

```
    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent event, Context context) {

        update = MAPPER.readValue(event.getBody(), Update.class);

        if (!update.hasMessage()) {
            return new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent()
                    .withStatusCode(200) // -> !!!!!! return code 200
                    .withBody("message is missing")
                    .withIsBase64Encoded(false);
        }
        ... ... ...
```